# How to get smtp error code using phpmailer

Tags: smtp, phpmailer

I got mail error message for smtp using phpmailer. but I need error code that error message.

How I get it.

Thanks

Comment: Please be a bit more specific on your question. Post some codes. Where are you stuck exactly? What exactly is the error that is occurring?

Comment: You should share with us what you've tried so far. (Note that you can edit your question to add details at any time)

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a connection error with the mail server. You should try to make a telnet conecction or a ping from the apllication server where you are running PHP to the  mail server like

```
telnet <mail_host> <port>
```

Also you should check Firewall settings on the server.